# Async .mjs works when calling directly, fails when called from another .mjs

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am currently working with the Ring-Client-API and am running into a small issue at the very end of my development. I succesfully created, tested, and ran my RingListener as an individual file, ie by executing RingListener.mjs. My goal is to now start the listener from another file location, and I am running into some issues trying to do that. I am more familiar with CommonJS so please feel free to point me in the right direction for ES6 stuff I am missing. I am running node 14.15.4

Code RingListener.mjs:

```
import {RingApi} from 'ring-client-api'
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({path: '../.env'});
import {readFile, writeFile} from 'fs'
import {promisify} from 'util'
import App from "../objects/GoogleHomeNotification.js";

export async function start() {
    const {env} = process;
    console.log("Test 1")
    const ringApi = new RingApi({my credentials});
    console.log("Test 2")
    const allCameras = await ringApi.getCameras();
    console.log("Test 3")
    console.log("Found " + allCameras.length + " camera(s)")
    ringApi.onRefreshTokenUpdated.subscribe(
        async ({newRefreshToken, oldRefreshToken}) => {
            console.log('Refresh Token Updated: ', newRefreshToken)
        }
    )
    if (allCameras.length) {
        console.log('Listening for motion and doorbell presses on your cameras.')
    }
}
start();
```

Output for RingListener.mjs

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Found 1 camera(s).
Refresh Token Updated: {my token}
Now writing it to proper .env file
Listening for motion and doorbell presses on your cameras.
```

When I try to start it from my other file, I only reach Test 2.
Start.mjs

```
import {start} from './objects/RingListener.mjs'

start();
//await start(); //Returns the same results as just start()
```

Output for Start.mjs

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

When running it from another location it seems to get stuck at the first await statement, and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am quite stumped because I am able to actually execute the function and I get the console log statements, but for some reason it keeps failing at the exact same spot with the await call when executed through another file. Is there something I am missing when calling an async function from another file?

Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks @JoshA for pointing me in the right direction for the filepath for dotenv.

The following code now hangs on the "Test 1 Test 2" when I try to import another js module.

```
import {start} from './objects/RingListener.mjs'
import {default as Webserver} from './app.js' 

await start();
```

Output

```
Test 1 
Test 2
```

But when I remove my import to the other class it runs perfectly, IE "Test 1, 2, 3, etc".

```
 import {start} from './objects/RingListener.mjs'
//import {default as Webserver} from './app.js'

await start();
```

Output

```
Test 1 
Test 2
Test 3
Found 1 camera(s).
Refresh Token Updated:  
Now writing it to proper .env file
Listening for motion and doorbell presses on your cameras.
```

I'm not even using it yet and it still is causing it to hang. Eventually I am going to use Webserver.listen(); but the ./app.js just exports the express app.

EDIT: The app.js contains a bunch of variable initialization and express app configuration. Mapping to the different routes on the server. The goal is to remove the app.listen() in the app.js and move it to the Start.mjs and call it by Webserver.listen() from the import.

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
require('dotenv').config()

/* Variable def here */

var app = express();
// app config here

/*  Exports  */
module.exports = app;

app.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log("Starting server on 1337");
})
```

Comment: Did you remove the `start()` call from the *RingListener.mjs* code when using it in *Start.mjs*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `dotenv` to load your credentials from your `.env` file which you then pass on to the `new RingApi({my credentials})` constructor.

If that's the case, the most likely reason it's failing is that `dotenv` uses [fs.readFileSync](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/6e17670da989de587254dfefade211151529269f/lib/main.js#L96) to read the `.env` file which looks for files relative to the path where node js was executed and not relative to the path of the module. Which is why it stops working if you execute the app from the `Start.mjs` which is in a different path.

If you really want to keep the dotenv config call inside your `RingListener.mjs` file you can rewrite it to something like this which resolves the absolute path for the `.env` file.

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
dotenv.config({path: resolve(__dirname, '../.env')});
```

If you get an error `__dirname is not defined` this is because it's not available in ECMAScript modules as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_filename_or_dirname).

As a workaround, you can do something like this.

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, resolve } from 'path';

// Initialize __dirname
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

// Then use it to resolve path for .env
dotenv.config({path: resolve(__dirname, '../.env')});
```

Comment: I believe that was the issue, thank you very much! I was able to start it from another file once I had the .env file path corrected! However when I try to run it with any other .js module in it, it freezes. See edit above if you have any suggestions!

Comment: No worries! I'll need to see what's inside `app.js` to be able to tell what's going on but just making a rough guess here, is it possible that you need to rename `app.js` to `app.mjs` and make sure that it's actually an ES module as opposed to a common js file?

Comment: I attached the contents of the app.js, it should be a common js file, I originally wrote this setup in common js but one library I needed only had as an ES module which is why I am trying to run it like this.

Comment: It looks like you're resetting dotenv again by calling `require('dotenv').config()` without the path to the `.env` file from inside `app.js`.

You only really need to call dotenv.config() once and ideally at the start of your app's entry file.

It seems your app's entry file is `Start.mjs` so you should probably move your `dotenv.config()` call into that file and make sure the path to your `.env` file is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help! So I moved the dotenv to the Start.js, turns out was in my app.js, I was importing a bunch of files to act as routers for express, and one of them was calling an out of date library as an import, once I removed that everything started to work well. Thank you again!